# How to get JSON result into List

Tags: c#, interface, json.net

I have my own code here and already get the JSON result then I haven't idea to move the JSON result into the interface (`IEntities` function) list below.

```
class GetCategory : IEntities
{
    private JsonHandle _jsonhandle;
    private string _ocategory;

    public async void TaskCategory()
    {
        _jsonhandle = new JsonHandle();
        _jsonhandle.StrAPI = "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/names.json?api-key=7bb034b7693d6f9753b2f68e00b98c78%3A16%3A73599437";
        var client = new HttpClient();
        Task<string> datatask = client.GetStringAsync(_jsonhandle.StrAPI);
        try
        {
            var JsonRead = await datatask;
            JObject oCategory = JObject.Parse(JsonRead);
            List<JToken> results = oCategory["results"].Children().ToList();

            //serialize JSON results into .NET objects
            List<object> dtCategory = new List<object>();
            foreach (JToken result in results)
            {
                object _dtcategory = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(result.ToString());
                dtCategory.Add(_dtcategory);
                var listname = result["list_name"];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AW!" + error.StackTrace);
        }

    public List<object> BookCategory()
    {

    }
}
```

In the last function that in `IEntities` interface, I need to put my JSON result in interface `List<object>`.

Comment: `List<T>` is not an interface...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with **JSON**, the first thing to do is creating a **model object**. In order to this, either you should analyze **JSON** output manually, or you can generate the model automatically by going to the following link and pasting either the JSON your are going to use or the service link;

[json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/)

I've just used your API link and the output generated is;

```
public class Result
{
    public string list_name { get; set; }
    public string display_name { get; set; }
    public string list_name_encoded { get; set; }
    public string oldest_published_date { get; set; }
    public string newest_published_date { get; set; }
    public string updated { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string copyright { get; set; }
    public int num_results { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}
```

This will be our model.

Secondly, as far as I can see, what you want to do is only to get the result list, thus, as you deserialize the **JSON** output, you are going to use the **Model.Result** and move them into a **list**.

Then, to get the response, a private method can be used which that returns an `async Task<string>`, and on the `BookCategory()` method, you can get the Results and deserialize **JSON** and initialize a list based on your **JSON object model**;

```
public List<Model.Result> BookCategory()
{
    List<Model.Result> list = new List<Model.Result>();

    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.RootObject>(TaskCategory().Result);

    list = model.results;

    return list;
}
```

**Deserializing JSON** is as simply as below;

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.RootObject>(TaskCategory().Result);
```

## Model.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SO1
{
    public class Model
    {
        public class Result
        {
            public string list_name { get; set; }
            public string display_name { get; set; }
            public string list_name_encoded { get; set; }
            public string oldest_published_date { get; set; }
            public string newest_published_date { get; set; }
            public string updated { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public string status { get; set; }
            public string copyright { get; set; }
            public int num_results { get; set; }
            public List<Result> results { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

## GetCategory.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System;

namespace SO1
{
    public class GetCategory : IEntities
    {
        private String BaseUri;

        public GetCategory(string BaseUri)
        {
            this.BaseUri = BaseUri;
        }

        private async Task<string> TaskCategory()
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            parameters["text"] = "text";

            var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(BaseUri);

            return response;        
        }

        public List<Model.Result> BookCategory()
        {
            List<Model.Result> list = new List<Model.Result>();

            var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.RootObject>(TaskCategory().Result);

            list = model.results;

            return list;
        }

    }
}
```

## IEntities

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SO1
{
    public interface IEntities
    {
        List<Model.Result> BookCategory();
    }
}
```

## Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SO1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string BaseUri = "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/names.json?api-key=7bb034b7693d6f9753b2f68e00b98c78%3A16%3A73599437";

            IEntities entity = new GetCategory(BaseUri);

            List<Model.Result> listBookCategory = new List<Model.Result>();

            listBookCategory = entity.BookCategory();

            foreach (Model.Result r in listBookCategory)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("...List Name             : " + r.list_name);
                Console.WriteLine("...Display Name          : " + r.display_name);
                Console.WriteLine("...List Name Encoded     : " + r.list_name_encoded);
                Console.WriteLine("...Oldest Published Date : " + r.oldest_published_date);
                Console.WriteLine("...Oldest Published Date : " + r.newest_published_date);
                Console.WriteLine("...Updated               : " + r.updated);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Output (only first three results printed)

```
...List Name             : Combined Print and E-Book Fiction
...Display Name          : Combined Print & E-Book Fiction
...List Name Encoded     : combined-print-and-e-book-fiction
...Oldest Published Date : 2011-02-13
...Oldest Published Date : 2015-12-27
...Updated               : WEEKLY


...List Name             : Combined Print and E-Book Nonfiction
...Display Name          : Combined Print & E-Book Nonfiction
...List Name Encoded     : combined-print-and-e-book-nonfiction
...Oldest Published Date : 2011-02-13
...Oldest Published Date : 2015-12-27
...Updated               : WEEKLY


...List Name             : Hardcover Fiction
...Display Name          : Hardcover Fiction
...List Name Encoded     : hardcover-fiction
...Oldest Published Date : 2008-06-08
...Oldest Published Date : 2015-12-27
...Updated               : WEEKLY
```